# Why can't I reinstall MySQL?

Tags: installation, uninstall, mysql

- List item

I've been looking all around the Internet for an answer but didn't find anything. I hope you can help me now.

I have a server with MySQL. From one day to another, MySQL didn't let me enter with my root password anymore (`accsess denied for user 'root'@'localhost' using password: 'YES'`). So I tried two ways to reset the password:

No.1: I typed:

```
    shell> /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

To stop MySQL. Then I restarted it skipping the grant-tables:

```
    shell> mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

So I was able to log in as root and change the password using:

```
    mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password = PASSWORD('MyNewPassword') WHERE User = 'root';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I restarted MySQL and tried to log in as root with my new password - didn't work. So I tried the solution that's described here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html (I don't want to post it here because this post is already pretty long). Didn't work either. Actually it made it worse, because since that day, every time I try to start MySQL, it doesn't even ask me for my password, but I get:

```
    shell> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

Well, I've looked up what it means and found that my `mysqld.sock` is missing. I tried to create it using `touch` but MySQL can't start with that socket.

Now I'm trying to reinstall MySQL but everytime I type in

```
    shell> apt-get --purge remove mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client
```

In that or any other order or every one of those three alone, I get:

```
    shell> Reading package lists... Done
    shell> Building dependency tree       
    shell> Reading state information... Done
    shell> Package mysql-client is not installed, so not removed
    shell> Package mysql-server is not installed, so not removed
    shell> You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
    shell> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    shell>  libmysqlclient18 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
    shell>  libmysqlclient18:i386 : Depends: mysql-common:i386 (>= 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.2)
    shell>  mysql-client-5.5 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
    shell>  mysql-server-5.5 : PreDepends: mysql-common (>= 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
    shell>  psa-firewall : Depends: plesk-core (>= 11.0.9) but it is not installable
    shell>                 Depends: mysql-server but it is not going to be installed
    shell>  psa-spamassassin : Depends: plesk-core (>= 11.0.9) but it is not installable
    shell>  psa-vpn : Depends: plesk-core (>= 11.0.9) but it is not installable
    shell>            Depends: plesk-base (>= 11.0.9) but it is not installable
    shell>            Depends: mysql-server but it is not going to be installed
    shell> E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I said to my self "let's just remove those files with depenencies, too" (that psa-stuff since plesk is virtual and can't be uninstalled)... Guess what happened:

```
    shell> Reading package lists... Done
    shell> Building dependency tree       
    shell> Reading state information... Done
    shell> Package mysql-client is not installed, so not removed
    shell> Package mysql-server is not installed, so not removed
    shell> You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
    shell> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    shell>  libmysqlclient18 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
    shell>  libmysqlclient18:i386 : Depends: mysql-common:i386 (>= 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.2)
    shell>  mysql-client-5.5 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
    shell>  mysql-server-5.5 : PreDepends: mysql-common (>= 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
    shell> E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Of course I tried `apt-get -f install`, too many times even.

What am I doing wrong? No matter, which other packages I include into `apt-get --purge remove`, I always get new dependencies. Do I have to delete every MySQL-related directory and file manually?
Hope there's someone out there who can help me!

Cheers!

EDIT:

After trying
        apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client libmysqlclient18 libmysqlclient18:i386 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 psa-firewall psa-spamassassin psa-vpn

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Package mysql-client is not installed, so not removed
    Package mysql-server is not installed, so not removed
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libdbd-mysql-perl : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.13-1) but it is not going to be installed
     libmyodbc : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.13-1) but it is not going to be installed
     libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 : Depends: libmysqlclient18:i386 (>= 5.5.13-1) but it is not going to be installed
     php5-mysql : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.13-1) but it is not going to be installed
     ruby-mysql : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.13-1) but it is not going to be installed
     E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I tried to remove all these and got:

```
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Package mysql-client is not installed, so not removed
    Package mysql-server is not installed, so not removed
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:qlclient18:i386 mysql
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libmysql-ruby1.8 : Depends: ruby-mysql but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

S I tried removing that last file, too and was already looking forward to having my problem solved - but I got this:

```
    (Reading database ... 73213 files and directories currently installed.)
    Removing psa-imp ...
    dpkg action: 
     Trying to start service mysql... /usr/sbin/mysqld (pid 14824) is running...
    done
     Trying to establish test connection... ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
    ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

Where I got the last line quite many times. After that there was this:

```
    failed

    ERROR while trying to establish test connection
    Check the error reason(see log file: /tmp/plesk_11.0.9_installation.log), fix and try again

    dpkg action: 
     Trying to start service mysql... /usr/sbin/mysqld (pid 14824) is running...
    done
     Trying to establish test connection... ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

And of course my favourite line was there like a houndret times again
The last line was just

`E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you do: `apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client libmysqlclient18 libmysqlclient18:i386 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 psa-firewall psa-spamassassin psa-vpn`?

Comment: As I said, it return more dependencies and `E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).` -.-

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to know which packages are still broken after the above command, because it removes all the packages listed in error messages.

Comment: try running `sudo apt-get autoremove` - this should remove anything that depends on the removed packages; then try `purge` again

Comment: using sudo gave me: `Reading package lists... Done5 php5-mysql ruby-mysql libmysql-ruby1.8
Building dependency tree        php5-mysql ruby-mysql libmysql-ruby1.8
Reading state information... Donephp5-mysql ruby-mysql libmysql-ruby1.8
E: Unable to locate package removeuby1.8bc libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 mysql-server-5.5
`

Comment: @Eric: I updated the post so you can see what happens when I try to remove every package that has a dependency here.

I also tried `aptitude --purge remove mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server` . Then the shell offered me a soulution: Removing more than 200 other packages and leave about ten dependencies unresolved. Can I do that without completely disabling the server?
Sorry if that last querstion was unnecessary but I'm quite a noob on this ;-)

Comment: Can you check if there's a file named `psa-imp.postrm` or `psa-imp.prerm` inside `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`?

Comment: Yes, they're both there. I also found dpkg.postinst ans dpkg.preinst Is that good or bad? :-S Do I have to modify any of them? If so, what part exactly?

Comment: Whoops, sorry! Of course I meant `psa-imp.postinst` and `psa-imp.preinst`.

Comment: From which repository did you install `psa-imp`?

Comment: Actually, I don't know :D it was just there. I reinstalled the whole server and now I can log in again *phew* ! Yet now I have another problem :D Maybe I'll ask another question for that. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me! (=